# Is the MongoDB C++ driver thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mongodb

As far as I have read, the MongoDB C++ driver is not thread safe. After some painful personal experiences with programming a multi-threaded HTTP server that persist information in MongoDB using this driver, it can confirm so (at the end, we used semaphores to avoid concurrent usage of driver functions).

Thus:

- Is that correct for all versions of the driver (I've tested with 2.2.3) or thread safeness is implemented in some later versions?
- Is there any other mechanism to use the driver in multi-threaded programs apart from the "classical" one about using semaphores? E.g. some specific functions in the driver API to easy the work.

It will be great to have some feedback from other users of the C++ driver! :) Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

---

Fermín

Comment: @Sammaye: Please point out a duplicate question on SO. Sending OP to giggle is not what this site is for.

Comment: @VladLazarenko giggle? Also if I feel this question is duplicate what is wrong with asking him to Google before coming here?

Comment: @Sammaye: This site is not affiliated with any search engines. If you feel it is a duplicate, then find a duplicate and point it out. Otherwise your comment it useless.

Comment: @VladLazarenko again I am not affiliating SO with a search engine I am merely pointing out that the OP might gain an answer from searching and then asking. Maybe I should have said bing it (nope) or Yahoo it (yeah...no), either way I commented that he might find a decent answer on a search engine.

Comment: Here is a google group thread on it too from searching: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/11c4vhnmf7/c-driver-thread-safe-connection-to-replica-set

Comment: @VladLazarenko in fact when ever you close a question as off topic because it is about recommending a tool you are infact pointing someone to a search engine cos that is the whole reason for closing those sorts of questions, is that Google or whatever should be doing that job

Comment: @Sammaye: Off-topic and duplicate questions are two different things.

Comment: @VladLazarenko but I am giving the same response, a response you say I shouldn't

Comment: You should be using ScopedDbConnections in each of your threads.